# SQL Server 2008 R2 not starting after moving model database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, system-databases

SQL Server 2008 R2 not starting after moving model database. Any ideas? Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.  Any ideas?
Sql 2008 R2 will not start with trace -f -T3608 or single user mode -m. Need params to start SMS to move Model back.

Answer (score 6):

You probably moved the model database without issuing the required ALTER DATABASE statements. In the errorlog you will find the path where SQL Server expects to find the model database files (data and log) and you can move back the files to that location and start the service again.

After the service has started, you can follow the instructions given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx) to move the model database to a different location.

Another possible cause could be the SQL Server service account is unable to access the path where the model database files are stored. Again, you can check it in the errorlog.

Answer (score 5):

`model` is required to build `tempdb`. W/o `tempdb` the server cannot start. Your best action is to move back `model` to where the engine expects it. Applying TF 3608 (`do not recover any database except master`) would not help in this situation.

A workaround on how to start the engine in a similar case (Eg. corrupted model) is given at [Why does restoring a database needs TempDB?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ialonso/why-does-restoring-a-database-needs-tempdb). Alonso uses TF 3609 (`Do not recreate tempdb, try to recover it as is`) to start up the engine even when `model` is not present, but it requires `tempdb` from previous successful run to be in a recoverable state.